# Login window, can't change brightness

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen, login

So, after reinstalling MacOs I bumped into an issue regarding login window. Before reinstallation system started first (Apple logo appeared and the loading line under the logo) and after there got login window. But now when I start MacBook I get an Apple logo without the line above, in a second I get login window (while having that login window I can't change the brightness of the screen & keyboard). After entering the password in the login screen I get that loading line under the password. Afterwards, system is starting.
That moment is bothering me as while having login window the keyboard brightness is 0 and cannot be changed.
How can it be fixed?
MacBook Pro 13" 2017

Comment: Simply speaking, the problem is that I got the login screen before the system is actually starting

Comment: Also, in order to start the system in safe mode, I have to enter my password first, then hold 'Shift'. Why Is the login window going first?